# Errorlevel 5 when starting executeable on Windows XP

Tags: c#, .net

Tested on Windows XP 32Bit with ServicePack 3 and .NET Versions 3.5, 4.0

The Executeable works on Windows 7 64bit and on Windows Server 2003 32bit perfectly, but on Windows XP 32Bit there is the following error when trying to install it with the ClickOnce Application Manager:

> Unable to install or run the application. The
>   application required that assembly
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.DebuggerVisualizer Version 11.0.0.0 be
>   installed in the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) first.
>
> Please contact your System Administrator

Or the following message when directly launching the .exe

> "Filename.exe is not a valid Win32 application"

The errorlevel I get after running it from CMD is 5

Project Settings:
.Net Framework 3.5 
Compiling in x86

Comment: That error seems kind of obvious. How are you unable to install the DebuggerVisualizer assembly?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the Problem by compiling the application on Visual Studio 2010. 
It worked like a charm on Windows XP.